# Unknown smd device from ST replacement possible?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, ups

first time here

I would like to ask what is the blown up device on the picture. I think its somekind of diode. I searched the ST site, but I didnt find anything with these markings. The board is from an APC BacUPS 600.

Picture of the device
[image]

EDIT
Thanks for the identification. Do you know of any parts that i can use to replace this one? Sucks that this one is obsolete.

Comment: Have a look at the datasheet for STTA206S. That has the marking T51.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the above comment by DiBosco, If you search for `ST T51 diode`, the datasheet catalogue for the [STTA206S](http://STTA206S%20-%20Datasheet%20catalog) will come up.

As per the catalogue this is an **ultra-fast high voltage diode**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its obsolete. Can i just replace with some generic HV diode?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Depends on the use case. I would suggest checking the main specifications from the above datasheet and comparing to your generic diode.

Comment: Yes, well done for copying what I'd already posted. :p You should not just replace with any old diode. It's a superfast device and is probably specified for a reason. Seek out something with the same (or better) characteristics.

Comment: @DiBosco I can reference you in the answer, however I searched using the above keywords which led me to the same result ;) Also you are right in saying that any old diode should not be used, but this still depends on the use case, which the OP has not shared with us.

Comment: I really don't care about being referenced, I'm not precious about it, it's all fine. That's what I put the smiley.  :)

Comment: @DiBosco: This is exactly why, if you're going to post an answer, you should make it an actual answer, not a comment.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know, I stress I was joking, I really don't care. On top of that, I wasn't 100% sure that was definitely the device.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the fault that caused the part to fail may be more important than finding just finding a replacement.  ST make many newer parts that will work, but I just happened to find one made by Diodes Inc.

US3M-13
Rectifiers 3.0A Ultra Fast Rec 25pF 1000 Vrrm 1.8V

This has lower capacitance and higher Vr (1000V) than original part (600V)

https://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/US3M-13/?qs=AsTZqt%2fmeqn6P6j1rpiT%252bg%3d%3d